# search string and delete matching line

Tags: python, python-3.x

First i am reading a file from AWS S3.

```
sample_html = client.get_object(Bucket=sample_bucket, Key='/temp/sample.html')
sample_html = sample_html['Body'].read().decode("UTF-8")
```

Suppose the sample_html now contains the following text.

```
sample_html = "<p>this is a sample text</p>
<div id=1234>this is a sample and sample text</div>
<figure>this is again a sample text</figure>
<p>this is a sample text</p>"
```

How to search "1234" string and delete the entire line? so the output could be something like:

```
"<p>this is a sample text</p>
<figure>this is again a sample text</figure>
<p>this is a sample text</p>"
```

Comment: when you say "delete the line" you have absolutely no guarantee that will leave you with valid html right?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I am absolutely sure it will be a valid HTML as tags are added by me in the code and each line has valid HTML closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text contains lines which have "hidden" characters "\n" which are used as a line break. Therefore you can use that to split the text into line.
After that you can filter that list as shown below:

```
sample_html = '''<p>this is a sample text</p>
<div id=1234>this is a sample and sample text</div>
<figure>this is again a sample text</figure>
<p>this is a sample text</p>'''

sample_html_out = []
for line in sample_html.split("\n"):
    print(line)
    if "1234" not in line:
        sample_html_out.append(line)
        
print("\n".join(sample_html_out))
```

---

or as one line:

```
print("\n".join([l for l in sample_html.split("\n") if "1234" not in l]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one liner `"\n".join(line for line in sample_html.split("\n") if "1234" not in line)`

```
In [2]: sample_html = """<p>this is a sample text</p>
   ...: <div id=1234>this is a sample and sample text</div>
   ...: <figure>this is again a sample text</figure>
   ...: <p>this is a sample text</p>"""

In [3]: "\n".join(line for line in sample_html.split("\n") if "1234" not in line)
Out[3]: '<p>this is a sample text</p>\n<figure>this is again a sample text</figure>\n<p>this is a sample text</p>'

In [4]: print(_)
<p>this is a sample text</p>
<figure>this is again a sample text</figure>
<p>this is a sample text</p>

In [5]:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of filtered lines with the following command (see [list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)):

```
[ln for ln in sample_html.split('\n') if not '1234' in ln]
```

If you want to get back a string, use the `join` function:

```
'\n'.join([ln for ln in sample_html.split('\n') if not '1234' in ln])
```